# Google Maps API V3 - Messy Controllers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to run the first example in the tutorial, and it works fine, except that my controller (zoom, etc..) are all messy.
I'm using V3.
Please take a look in the image:
[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:800px; height:600px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                myOptions);


});
    </script>
```

Thoughts?
Thanks

Solution:

If this ever happens to you, take a look at your css.
In my case, I was adding some padding to the divs, and it also affected divs inside google maps area.

Comment: post the solution as answer and accept!

Answer (score 0):

first of all check on another browser (if you didn't yet). If other browser displays it right try to set position of UI by yourself like [here](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#ControlPositioning)

If problem still exist nothing more is comming to my head.

Mariusz

Comment: It looks the same in other browsers.
Anyway, I just found that disabling my css makes it work. I'm not sure why... I did not know that my css would interfere with the API. Now I will need to find exactly what is confliting.